# I can't load the modules from the standard library in python

Tags: python, module, attributeerror

The problem is only in visual studio and atom, in the python IDLE my code runs perfectly. 
When I try to import the math module and call the sqrt function it doesn't work and I only get the error:

> ```
> "AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'sqrt'"
> ```

I tried reinstalling python and pip but the same problem came up again.
First I though the problem was with atom so I deleted it and installed visual studio but it was just a waste of time.

```
import math

x = math.sqrt(25)

print(x)
```

I've been trying to fix this bug/error for hours but still nothing and I'm starting to feel hopeless.

Comment: Do you have a file called `math.py` anywhere in the working directory?

Comment: can you post the output of `math.__file__`? This will let us know where it's getting imported from.